# the sort of people that disillusion you about what a lot of golfing money can do for the personality

Tags: meaning

Here's from The Long Goodby by Raymond Chandler

> At The Dancers they get the sort of people that disillusion you about what a lot of golfing money can do for the personality.

I wonder What this means,
particularly what "golfing money" means.

A similar question was asked here.
https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/198810/what-is-golfing-money

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Dancers is (likely - I haven't read it) a country club, which usually has a golf course. Country clubs cost a lot of money to join; on top of that, a golf game costs a lot of money for each game. *Golf money* would imply that someone has enough money to play golf.

In the US, an positive emphasis for many decades (perhaps centuries) was/is placed on being "self-made" - working hard enough to become rich, that is, having all the niceties of life, like a country club membership and *golf money*. One would think that the character formed from a solid work ethic would bring out good qualities in people. Chandler says it does not; in fact, a lot of money seems to bring out bad traits in people, hence the *disillusionment*.

Comment: @MakotoKato: the very first line of the book is: *The first time I laid eyes on Terry Lennox he was drunk in a Rolls-Royce Silver Wraith outside the terrace of The Dancers.* A Rolls-Royce is ***not*** the kind of car driven by a person who goes to *"ordinary joints"*, as you referred to *The Dancers*.

Answer (score 2):

Golf is a wealthy man's game. "Golfing money" in this sense means money that is spent on pointless leisure activity. The passage is a comment on upper class people behaving badly, and the kind of business that caters to those people.

Answer (score -1):

Ordinarily, you would hope that gaining wealth would improve a person's behaviour and general character as much it improved their bank account. Sadly, this tends not to be the case - excess wealth has a tendency to instead amplify a person's flaws.

Here, 'The Dancers' (a club in the story) attracts wealthy people, and the narrator is stating that their behaviour proves that point. 'Golfing money', in this context, likely refers to wealth gained through the playing of professional golf.